# Difficulty in retrieving the return data in chained promises in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I am trying to find ways to work around the asynchronous nature of AngularJS by using chained promises.

I have however difficulties obtaining the return data when there are multiple chains. In the following, `function1()` returns a *deferred promise* `(output1)`, which I want to pass on in functions `step2()` and `step3()`. What is the way to do so?

```
dataList.get().$loaded()
    .then(function step1() { initCanvas(); return function1() })
    .then(function step2(output1) { function2(output1); })
    .then(function step3(output1) { function3(output1); $scope.loading = false; })
    .catch(function(error) {
      window.alert("Error: " + error)
      $scope.loading = false;
});//dataList()
```

---

**SOLUTION**

```
dataList.get().$loaded()
        .then(function step1() { initCanvas(); return function1() })
        .then(function step2(output1) { function2(output1); return output1;}) // add return statement!!
        .then(function step3(output1) { function3(output1); $scope.loading = false; })
        .catch(function(error) {
          window.alert("Error: " + error)
          $scope.loading = false;
    });//dataList()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each .then part of the chain, you need to return the data you want passed to the next part of the chain.

```
.then(function(prevThenReturn) {
     return 'a';
}).then(function(thisEqualsA) {
    console.log(thisEqualsA)
})
```